# Custom DropdownlistFor cannot be Validated with jQuery.Validate()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, html-helper, html-select, html.dropdownlistfor

I created a custom helper method containing a DropdownlistFor method. When I select the -1. index, the other Dropdownlists can directly be validated. On the other hand, the custom Dropdownlist is not validated until submitting the form and returning to the prior page. Here are my custom helper method and usage of the custom DropdownlistFor in Razor.

**My Custom Helper:**

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyDropdownList(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, IEnumerable<MySelectItem> list, string optionLabel, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    TagBuilder dropdown = new TagBuilder("select");
    dropdown.Attributes.Add("name", name);
    dropdown.Attributes.Add("id", name);
    StringBuilder options = new StringBuilder();

    // Make optionLabel the first item that gets rendered.
    if (optionLabel != null)
        options = options.Append("<option value='" + String.Empty + "'>" + optionLabel + "</option>");

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        if(item.Disabled == "disabled")
            options = options.Append("<option value='" + item.Value + "' class='" + item.Class + "' disabled='" + item.Disabled + "'>" + item.Text + "</option>");
        else
            options = options.Append("<option value='" + item.Value + "' class='" + item.Class + "'>" + item.Text + "</option>");
    }
    dropdown.InnerHtml = options.ToString();
    dropdown.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(dropdown.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

**Razor:**

```
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Applicant.MeetingId)              
@Html.MyDropdownListFor(m => m.Applicant.MeetingId, 
  ViewBag.MeetingData as List<MyHelpers.MySelectItem>, 
  null, new { name = "meetingId", id = "meetingId"})                   
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Applicant.MeetingId, null , 
  new { @class = "ValidationErrors" })
```

**--- UPDATE I --------------------------------------------------------------------------**

```
public class MySelectItem : SelectListItem
{            
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public string Disabled { get; set; }
}


public static MvcHtmlString MyDropdownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<MySelectItem> list, string optionLabel, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    if (expression == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");
    }
    ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<TModel, TProperty>(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
    string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText((LambdaExpression)expression);
    return MyDropdownList(htmlHelper, metadata, name, optionLabel, list, HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
}


private static MvcHtmlString MyDropdownList(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata metadata, string name, string optionLabel, IEnumerable<MySelectItem> list, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    string fullName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fullName))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("name");
    }

    TagBuilder dropdown = new TagBuilder("select");
    dropdown.Attributes.Add("name", fullName);
    dropdown.GenerateId(fullName);
    dropdown.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes); //dropdown.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
    dropdown.MergeAttributes(htmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(name, metadata));

    StringBuilder options = new StringBuilder();

    // Make optionLabel the first item that gets rendered.
    if (optionLabel != null)
        options = options.Append("<option value='" + String.Empty + "'>" + optionLabel + "</option>");

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        if (item.Disabled == "disabled")
            options = options.Append("<option value='" + item.Value + "' class='" + item.Class + "' disabled='" + item.Disabled + "'>" + item.Text + "</option>");
        else
            options = options.Append("<option value='" + item.Value + "' class='" + item.Class + "'>" + item.Text + "</option>");
    }
    dropdown.InnerHtml = options.ToString();
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(dropdown.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

Comment: Please show the source code of MyDropdownListFor

Answer (score 2):

Your custom DropdownListFor must include the validation attributes. You do this by calling

`dropdown.MergeAttributes(htmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(name, metadata));`

Here is the modified code

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyDropdownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<MySelectItem> list, string optionLabel, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes = null)
{
    if (expression == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");
    }
    ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<TModel, TProperty>(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
    string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText((LambdaExpression) expression);
    return MyDropdownList(htmlHelper, metadata, name, optionLabel, list, htmlAttributes);
}

private static MvcHtmlString MyDropdownList(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata metadata, string name, string optionLabel, IEnumerable<MySelectItem> list, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    string fullName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fullName))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("name");
    }

    TagBuilder dropdown = new TagBuilder("select");
    dropdown.Attributes.Add("name", fullName);
    dropdown.GenerateId(fullName);
    dropdown.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    dropdown.MergeAttributes(htmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(name, metadata));

    StringBuilder options = new StringBuilder();

    // Make optionLabel the first item that gets rendered.
    if (optionLabel != null)
        options = options.Append("<option value='" + String.Empty + "'>" + optionLabel + "</option>");

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        if (item.Disabled == "disabled")
            options = options.Append("<option value='" + item.Value + "' class='" + item.Class + "' disabled='" + item.Disabled + "'>" + item.Text + "</option>");
        else
            options = options.Append("<option value='" + item.Value + "' class='" + item.Class + "'>" + item.Text + "</option>");
    }
    dropdown.InnerHtml = options.ToString();
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(dropdown.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

Also, don't forgot the include JQuery validation script in the view

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Some recommendations

1. Also use TagBuilder to construct the options element
2. You may want to show the currently selected value in your custom DropdownListFor
3. If validation failed in the server, you may want to add the validation failed CSS class

Lastly, if you want to call the client side validation manually, call

```
$(selector).valid()
```

Comment: It depends. If you will use JQuery validation in almost all of your views, you can add it to _Layout.cshtml. If you will seldom use it or your view doesn't use a layout, then add it to the specific view. [Intro to layouts](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx)

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help and nice suggestions. Now there is a little problem remained and I believe in that I can solve with the help of your help. Could you clarify me about the issue below one by one please? I added the Updayted code to my question above. 

I use jQuery validation methods by adding these lines to Razor View or Layout View:
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>

Comment: 1) What is the difference using Javascripts like above and using **@section Scripts** as suggested?

2) When I use javascripts as above the fields can be checked directly after focusing another input. But the fields cannot be validated after submitting the form. On the other hand, when I do not use **jquery.validate.js** (at the third line), this time all the mandatory form field can be validated after submitting. But this time they cannot be validated without submitting the form. I tried lots of different combinations and different javascript versions of the related files. What is problem?

Comment: 3) Could you please update your answer by using "TagBuilder" in order to contsruct option element?

4) I think in order to use Selected and Failed CSS property, I should define them as I did on public class MySelectItem : **SelectListItem{...}** on the updated code. Is that true? If yes, where can I integrate them to the options section? Could you update the code also integrating it please?

I think after applying the changes the problem will be solved completely. Thanks in advance. Regards.

Comment: Any idea regarding to my last questions?